# How to convert elastic search queries from Kibana 3 to Kibana 4

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, dashboard, kibana-4

I have created a dashboard in Kibana 3. I would like to replicate the same in Kibana 4.
 How can I replicate this elastic search query written in Kibana 3 to Kibana4?

Please find the below code:

```
( cf.cf_org_name:ABC OR cf.cf_org_name:DEF ) AND NOT (cf.msg:"Stopped span:" OR cf.msg:"Continued span:" OR cf.msg:"Starting span:" OR cf.msg:"*swagger*" OR cf.msg:"*\[my.Agent\]" OR cf.msg:"*\[my.Properties\]")
```

Any lead would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You can directly copy this query & use it in Search Bar of Discover Page to validate whether the query is working as desired or not.

Comment: no its not working there its of kibana3

Answer (score 0):

I read somewhere Kibana sets allow_leading_wildcard to false, so you may have to set allow_leading_wildcard to true in the settings/advanced tab of Kibana in the field query:queryString:options.

This is because you are using for example cf.msg:"*swagger*" in your query.